# What is the entropy of a Skellam distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

For programming purpose, I'd like to compare the entropy of two Poisson distributions to the entropy of a single [Skellam distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution).

The entropy of a Poisson distribution is given in this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) article.

What is the entropy of a Skellam distribution?